# Why is some information from the Wikipedia infobox missing on DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Why is some information from the Wikipedia infobox missing on DBpedia?

For example, [star Alpha Librae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Librae) has property *distance-from-earth* in the infobox, but it isn't a property of the [Alpha Librae dbpedia resource](http://dbpedia.org/page/Alpha_Librae). On the other hand, [star Betelgeuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse) has this piece of information on [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Betelgeuse)). And many other stars have this distance information in the infobox, but there isn't any matching property in the DBpedia resource.

Is there a way to extract thise missing information from DBpedia using SPARQL or is the only way web scraping of the wiki page?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so much as about what data DBpedia does and doesn't contain (at the present moment).  This would probably be better directed to a DBpedia-oriented forum (e.g., a DBpedia mailing list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DBpedia pages present all the data DBpedia has -- no SPARQL nor other query can get data that isn't there.

DBpedia is updated periodically. It may not reflect the latest changes on Wikipedia.

Also, extractors are a living project, and may not grab every property in which you're interested.

Looking at [Betelgeuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse) on Wikipedia, I see one distance in the infobox.  Looking at [Alpha_Librae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Librae), I see *two* distances. Which should DBpedia have? Perhaps you have the niche knowledge which can ensure that the extractors do the right thing...

As @JoshuaTaylor suggests, you will probably get more satisfactory answers from [the DBpedia discussion list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion) and/or [the DBpedia development list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-developers).

Comment: I think it's a same distance(for Alpha_Librae) but units are different(pc=parsec=3.26 light years and ly=light year).And Betelgeuse uses different properties for those different units(http://dbpedia.org/property/distPc and http://dbpedia.org/property/distLy).

Comment: But anyway thanks for your answer.It's a problem when the same property has multiple values(different measurements gave different results).I Thought  that dbpedia does only web scraping of a infobox but it seems that process is much more complex.Again sorry because of my poor English :)

Comment: Look at Alpha_Librae's Wikipedia page again?  In the "Astrometry" section of the infobox, note that there are *two* subsections, "a^1 Lib" and "a^2 Lib", and *each* has `distPc` and `distLy`. Betelgeuse only has one pair of `distPc` and `distLy`.

Comment: Yes but because it is a binary star(alpha 1 and alpha 2).For every constellation there is a wiki page (  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stars_in_Libra ) with data for all stars(many of stars on sky are binary systems or even more stars are at very close distance and looking from earth it seems that there is only one star).But those pages do not have infoboxes so those infos are not in dbpedia.Probably dbpedia software is confused (because of multiple infos for the same subject) and those infos are not extracted.

Comment: On the other hand Theta Librae for example has only one distance(in ly and pc units) in infobox but those informations are not extracted : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_Librae  ,  http://dbpedia.org/page/Theta_Librae .As you said this is question for dbepdia discussion list.

Answer (score 1):

Look at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Golf_Mk3:

In the infobox you have:

**height** = 1991-95 & Cabrio: {{convert|1422|mm|in|1|abbr=on}}
1996-99: {{convert|1428|mm|in|1|abbr=on}}

In dbpedia you get **height**=1991-95

instead of

**height**=1442

**height**=1428

This happens because there is no standard how to define properties in a conditional way. For this reason, dbpedia properties are sometimes wrong/missing

Comment: Yes sometimes properties in dbpedia are not correct.Thanks for your answer.